# $provide outside config blocks

Tags: angularjs, internals, angularjs-injector

I'm certainly missing some fundamental point about the injector, but I fail to understand why exactly this

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($provide) {
    ...
});
```

and this

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($injector) {
    $injector.invoke(function ($provide) { ... });
});
```

work as intended, while this

```
app.run(function($provide) {
    ...
});
```

will throw

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $provideProvider <- $provide

As follows from the above, `config` has some special relationship with providers, while `run` deals with instances, yet I'm unsure about the thing that makes `config` blocks so special.

As a consequence of that, is there no way to get to `$provide` outside `config` blocks, e.g. with `angular.injector()` (though it seems that it gets provider instances also)?

The question, besides mere curiosity, also has some practical considerations. In 1.4 all of `$provide` functions are exposed to module, but that's not true for 1.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some Angular injector study I was able to give an exhaustive answer to my own question.

Essentially, `$injector` [in `config` blocks and `provider` constructor functions](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/auto/injector.js#L633) and `$injector` [everywhere else](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/auto/injector.js#L641) are two different services with the same name, which are defined on internal provider/instance cache explicitly, together with `$provide` (this one is being defined in provider cache, hence it can be injected in `config` only).

While generally not recommended because of probable race conditions, it is possible to expose internal services to instance cache and make config-specific `$provide` and `$injector` available for injection after config phase has ended:

```
app.config(function ($provide, $injector) {
  $provide.value('$providerInjector', $injector);
  $provide.value('$provide', $provide);
});
```

The possible applications are configuring service providers any time (if possible)

```
app.run(function ($providerInjector) {
  var $compileProvider = $providerInjector.get('$compileProvider');
  ...
});
```

and defining new components at run-time

```
app.run(function ($provide) {
  $provide.controller(...);
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of the `config()` function is to allow you to perform some *global* configuration that will affect the entire application - that includes services, directives, controllers, etc. Because of that, the `config()` block must run before anything else. But, you still need a way to perform the aforementioned configuration and make it available to the rest of the app. And the way to do that is by using *providers*.

What makes providers "special" is that they have two initialization parts, and one of them is directly related to the `config()` block. Take a look at the following code:

```
app.provider('myService', function() {
    var self = {};    
    this.setSomeGlobalProperty = function(value) {
        self.someGlobalProperty = value;
    };

    this.$get = function(someDependency) {
        this.doSomething = function() {
            console.log(self.someGlobalProperty);
        };
    };    
});

app.config(function(myServiceProvider) {
    myServiceProvider.setSomeGlobalProperty('foobar');
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function(myService) {
    myService.doSomething();
});
```

When you inject a provider into the `config()` function, you can access anything **but** the `$get` function (technically you can access the `$get` function, but calling it won't work). That way you can do whatever configuration you might need to do. That's the first initialization part. It's worth mentioning that even though our service is called `myService`, you need to use the suffix `Provider` here.

But when you inject the same provider into any other place, Angular calls the `$get()` function and injects whatever it returns. That's the second initialization part. In this case, the provider behaves just like an ordinary service.

Now about `$provide` and `$injector`. Since they are "configuration services", it makes sense to me that you can't access them outside the `config()` block. If you could, then you would be able to, say, create a factory *after* it had been used by another service.

Finally, I haven't played with v1.4 yet, so I have no idea why that behavior apparently has changed. If anyone knows why, please let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, that's quality answer that will serve the community well. Currently I've advanced a bit further then that and can't learn anything new from the answer. I hoped that somebody would share his knowledge on ng internals. I guess I have to go through `bootstrap` and `$injector` and study them once more.

Comment: In 1.4 `module` finally exposes the whole API that `$provide` provides. It wasn't so in previous versions (`decorator` was missing at least) .