# AngularJS injecting a factory into a provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a module which must use the `provider` recipe as it requires configuration before runtime. I'm interested in modularizing my code, so I would like to inject some services into the provider. I'm aware that injecting `providers` into other `providers` is simple, but seems to be overkill for what I am trying to achieve, so I would like to inject a `factory` instead.

From what I understand, using the `$injector` during a runtime gives us access to the `instanceCache` through angular's `createInternalInjector` method which returns services which have been instantiated.

When using the `$injector` during the config phase, you get access to the `providerCache` which holds uninstantiated services.

I feel like this assumption must be incorrect though. In the code below, the `$injector` is being used in a provider but through a function that is called during the application's run phase. I would hope to get access to the `instanceCache` but I am only given access to the `providerCache` through the `$injector.get` method.

```
_tudModule.factory('wfTabletUsageDataCache', [
        function () {
            return {
                addToLog: fn () { … }
            }
        }
])


_tudModule.provider('$tabletUsageData', [
    '$injector', function $tabletUsageDataProvider ($injector) {

    function getCacheFactory() {
       return $injector.get('wfTabletUsageDataCacheProvider').$get();
    }

    function logInteraction(state, buttonId) {
        getCacheFactory().addToLog();           // fn() called
    }
]);
```

What about the `$injector` in a `provider` disables access to the `instanceCache`? Even when the methods in the provider are not being run during the `config` phase?

Also, I haven't seen the method I am using `$injector.get('wfTabletUsageDataCacheProvider').$get()` before. Though it works, is this a bad way to achieve such functionality?

Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the config phase, (`config()` blocks or providers) you can inject **providers** and **constants**, not factories, services, or values. If a provider is overkill for you, you can use a constant.

Something like this could work

```
_tudModule.constant('wfTabletUsageDataCache', {
  addToLog: function () { ... }
});

_tudModule.provider('$tabletUsageData', [ 'wfTabletUsageDataCache',
  function (wfTabletUsageDataCache) {
     wfTabletUsageDataCache.addToLog(...)
  }
]);
```

---

> When using the `$injector` during the config phase, you get access to the `providerCache` which holds uninstantiated services.

It appears that you're correct, but this usage is undocumented and in general discouraged. **`$injector` is a service, and it should not be injected into providers.**

---

> Also, I haven't seen the method I am using `$injector.get('...').$get()` before.

Providers are the lowest-level way of defining Angular services. All `.service()`, `.factory()`, or `.value()` definitions can be rewritten using `.provider()`. By definition, when the provider is instantiated, it must expose a `$get` method which is injectable and responsible for returning an instance of the service.

This is what you are seeing here. You are retrieving (and instantiating) the provider using `$injector.get(...)` and then creating the service instance using the `$get()` method. However, **this normally happens under the hood, and the `$get()` method is not meant to be called manually.**

You are essentially trying to hack around the limitation which does not allow instantiating services before the run-phase. This is not recommended.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help. Do you think injecting the ```constant``` or defining methods in the provider's ```$get``` function (as explained in the other answer) is preferable in this case?

Comment: If your `wfTabletUsageDataCache` has no dependencies (i.e. you don't need to inject anything to make it work) then a constant will do just fine. I am not sure I fully understand what the other answer is suggesting, but as far as I know, the only "correct" way to modularize functionality used to configure a service (i.e. within the provider) is a constant.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you do not need the `wfTabletUsageDataCache` while configuring `$tabletUsageData`, then you can keep it a factory (or anything else) and inject it into the provider's `$get` method rather than the provider constructor itself.

Comment: Great! Very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in your assumption. The thing that you've missed is that there are two different injectors, for service providers and for service instances. Once you've injected provider injector into `provider`, it will continue to deal with providers even after config phase. You may also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854811/provide-outside-config-blocks/33704523#33704523) for clarification.

Using `$injector.get('someProvider').$get()` will return a new service instance which is unrelated to `instanceCache` and is not a singleton. I.e.

```
$injector.get('someProvider').$get() !== $injector.get('someProvider').$get();
```

There's no magic behind `$get`, it is just a constructor function, and injector has no means or reasons to track its calls.

For the current code `factory` can be safely used instead of `provider`. If the provider has to be configured in `config`, all instance-related code should go to `$get` (because `factory` is just sugar syntax for `provider` with sole `$get` method).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. By all instance code should go to ```$get```, you mean ```provider('provider', function () { return {$get: function () { ... } } });```? Thanks for the help!