# reset myApp into body by angular.bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem. 
I wants design multiple modules, each module will config route for itself. And before login I just wants load 3 modules (with 3 route), and after login I continue load 3 module (with 3 route). So I need re-config myApp to add new routes, then re-set into body to apply myApp.

And my solution is: 
I create mainModule is myApp, and i config for it then I set into body by angular.bootstrap

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ["myApp"]);
});
```

Then, I need re-config for myApp and I set again.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
     angular.bootstrap(document.body, ["myApp"], true);
});
```

An error occurs

```
 [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element '&lt;body cz-shortcut-listen="true" class="ng-scope"&gt;'(…)
```

How can I reset myApp into body or any solution ??? 
Thanks,

Comment: You may read on re-bootstrapping [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/inception-one-angularjs-application-inside-another-m%C3%A1rquez-soto). However, you didn't mentioned why exactly this is necessary, and your case is most likely XY problem.

Comment: Thanks Estus, my issue is: I wants design multiple modules, each module will config route for itself. And before login I just wants load 3 modules (with 3 route), and after login I continue load 3 module (with 3 route). So I need re-config myApp to add new routes, then re-set into body to apply myApp.

Comment: Yes, recurring bootstrapping won't do any good to your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While lazy loading is not among listed features in Angular, some of the things which are intrinsic to config phase can be performed at run-time (while they cannot be recommended and belong to 'use at your own risk' category).

When provider is being used to configure the service before its instantiation, most likely (it depends on service implementation) it can be used to configure it after it was instantiated, e.g.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $provide) {
  // now $routeProvider is available for injection during both config and run phases
  $provide.constant('$routeProvider', $routeProvider);
});

app.run(function ($routeProvider,  $location) {
  $routeProvider.when('/brand-new-route', { ... });
  $location.path('/brand-new-route');
});
```

More of this injector trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704523/3731501).

This method isn't forbidden but relies on current service implementation and undocumented behaviour, so it has to be either tested thoroughly or should be avoided at all.

Comment: Great, Estus. And I have a question, can i reset  $routeProvider (remove all routes)?

Comment: @Sophia They are exposed in [$route.routes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#routes). And you don't have to do that. If the route needs to be denied on condition, do this on $routeChangeStart event. Feel free to post a question describing the whole picture if you need help on design decisions, it looks like you're doing something conventional the hard way.