# AngularJS 1.5 unit testing UI-Router state changes within controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, angular-ui-router, jasmine

I have a AngularJS 1.5 app in which I use the UI-Router. The problem I'm having is with unit testing my state changes within the controller.

I have the following logic in my controller

```
CostingsController = ($scope, $http, $state, flash) ->

  if $state.current.name == "costing_new"
    if $scope.current_division
      $http.get('/costings/new').then ((response) ->
        $scope.costing = response.data
      )
    else
      flash("alert", "Please select a division", 2000)
      $state.go "divisions"
```

I'm trying to test that the state changes to divisions when there is no division selected. This code works in practice but not in the tests. Here is my Jasmine test

```
  describe "when division is not selected", ->
    beforeEach(inject ( ($controller, $rootScope, $location, $state, $httpBackend) ->
      @state = $state
      @redirect = spyOn(@state, 'go')
      @state.transitionTo('costing_new')

      ctrl = $controller('CostingsController', {
        $scope: @scope,
        $location: $location,
        $state: @state
      })
    ))

    it "redirects to division", ->
      expect(@state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('divisions')
```

The error I get is;

```
Chrome 63.0.3239 (Linux 0.0.0) CostingsController Controller: costings_controller new when division is not selected redirects to division FAILED
    Expected spy go to have been called with [ 'divisions' ] but it was never called.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/map7/code/pais/spec/javascripts/unit/costing_controller_spec.js.js:47:40)
Chrome 63.0.3239 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 394 (1 FAILED) (skipped 393) ERROR (0.403 secs / 0.197 secs)
```

**Update: using angular.copy**

```
  describe "when division is not selected", ->
        beforeEach(inject ( ($controller, $rootScope, $location, $state, $httpBackend) ->
          @state = angular.copy({current: {name: 'costing_new'}}, $state)
          @redirect = spyOn(@state, 'go')

          ctrl = $controller('CostingsController', {
            $scope: @scope,
            $location: $location,
            $state: @state
          })
        ))

        it "redirects to division", ->
          expect(@state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('divisions')
```

If I use the above with angular.copy I get the following error;

```
TypeError: Cannot set property current of #<StateService> which has only a getter
```

Comment: Please, always state that the question uses Coffeescript, because most Angular(JS) devs aren't comfortable with this lingo. You're using something like `flash`, and it wasn't stubbed - while everything but the unit you're testing (controller) should be. I guess it pauses the script by calling alert, doesn't it?

Comment: flash is just a toast message it doesn't pause execution.

Comment: Consider mocking entire $state service for the same reason, as it breaks test isolation and makes it dependent on third-party unit. This is likely what happens here. The test relies on state.transitionTo behaviour, but it won't necessarily behave as you expect (it possibly requires $rootScope.$digest() or else). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899581/angular-jasmine-mock-stateparams-in-a-directive

Answer (score 0):

Taking estus help I've mocked state like so

```
  describe "when division is not selected", ->
    beforeEach(inject ( ($controller, $state) ->
      @state = {
        current: {name: "costing_new"},
        go: jasmine.createSpy("go")
      }

      ctrl = $controller('CostingsController', {
        $scope: @scope,
        $state: @state
      })
    ))

    fit "redirects to division", ->
      expect(@state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('divisions')
```