# Jasmine & Angular: Injecting a service into a service mock

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jasmine

We write a suite of unit tests for an Angular application with many services. It's convenient to provide fake service implementations, which generally do nothing, to be plugged into the app module, for example:

```
'use strict';

describe('ServiceUnderTest', function () {

    beforeEach(module('app', FakeServiceA, FakeServiceB));

    ...

}

// Fake service implementations (global functions):

function FakeServiceA($provide) {
    $provide.value(
        'ServiceA'
        { foo: function () {} }
    );
}

function FakeServiceB($provide) {
    $provide.value(
        'ServiceB'
        { bar: function () {} }
    );
}
```

Now, if I want them to actually do *something* instead of nothing, for instance, reject a promise, I hit the problem of injecting a dependency. What I want is:

```
function FakeServiceA($provide, $q) {
    $provide.value(
        'ServiceA'
        { foo: function () { return $q.reject('Nope!'); } }
    );
}
```

But it seems to be impossible to inject `$q` this way. Is there any other way how it can be achieved when registering a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q can't be injected this way

```
function FakeServiceA($provide, $q) { ...
```

because the specified dependencies are injected by provider injector, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704523/3731501) (the fact that `$provide` can be used there makes a hint about that), while service instances ($q) have to be injected by instance injector. Obviously, it can't inject `$q` because it wasn't instantiated from `$qProvider` at this point.

It has to be something like that:

```
function FakeServiceA($provide) {
    $provide.factory('ServiceA', function ($q) {
        return { foo: function () { return $q.reject('Nope!'); } }
    });
}
```

Comment: It works indeed, however it kind of violates the singleton pattern services are supposed to adhere to. But for unit-testing it's of no importance of course as they're recreated on each test anyway.

Comment: @yktoo Nothing really weird or hacky happens here. In fact, all that `$provide.value` does  under the hood is calling `$provide.factory` with empty factory function, and `$provide.factory` defines a singleton service.