# Why I am able to access angular service without injecting module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am playing with [angular services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) and finding that I am able to use an angular service without even injecting it's `module`. I have created 3 modules i.e. `moduleA, moduleB, app`. `moduleA` & `moduleB` are independent of each other but `app` module depends on `moduleA` and `moduleB`. This is how I am creating modules.

```
angular.module('moduleA',[]);
angular.module('moduleB',[]);
angular.module('app',['moduleA', 'moduleB']);
```

In `moduleA` I have a service `ServiceA` and in `moduleB` I have a service `ServiceB`. This how I am defining services:

**moduleA <-- ServiceA:**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('moduleA', []);
  app.service('ServiceA', function() {
    'use strict';
    this.greet = function() {
      alert('Greetings From Service A');
    };
  });
}());
```

**moduleB <-- ServiceB:** I have injected `serviceA` in `serviceB`.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('moduleB', []);
  app.service('ServiceB', function(ServiceA) {
    // I have not injected moduleA in moduleB but still
    // Don't know why I am able to access ServiceA
    // in ServiceB. Ideally I should not be able to access
    // anything which is defined in moudleA unlesss and until
    // I do not inject moduleA in moudleB.
    console.log(ServiceA);
    this.greet = function() {
      ServiceA.greet();
    };
  });
}());
```

And in the end
**app Module:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('app', ['moduleA', 'moduleB']);
  app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'ServiceA', 'ServiceB', function($scope, ServiceA, ServiceB) {
    $scope.greet = function() {
      ServiceB.greet();
    };
  }])
}());
```

Now the concern is that **I am not injecting `moduleA` in `moduleB` but still I am able to access `ServiceA` of `moduleA` in `ServiceB` of `moduleB`.** I don't know why this is happening. What I understand from module is that they are similar to `package` or `namespace` of Java or Dot Net. Whatever we create in a module lies in that particular module. To get services or special objects defined in that module I have to inject the module. But don't know why I am able to access it without even injecting it. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hitesh_kumar/pvqdLg3u/) to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a module is loaded, its services become available for injection. Once service provider is defined on current `$injector`, it holds no information which module it belongs to.

The code above is workable, but it designates a bad habit, because it will render unworkable if `moduleA` is not loaded. As a rule of thumb, modules should load modules which they depend on. It is acceptable to load a module in several dependent modules, it will be loaded only once.

The things become more complicated with provider injector in `config` block (there are [two separate `$injector`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704523/3731501) for service providers and service instances).

For this loading order

```
angular.module('app',['moduleA', 'moduleB']);
```

this will work as expected, because `ServiceA` service provider was already defined when `config` block runs:

```
angular.module('moduleB', []).config(function (ServiceAProvider) { ... });
```

And for this loading order

```
angular.module('app',['moduleB', 'moduleA']);
```

injector error will be thrown, because `config` block runs before `app.service('ServiceA', ...)` defines `ServiceAProvider` service provider. `app.service` method may run earlier than `config`, but service definitions are queued and don't take effect immediately.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you inject moduleA and moduleB in app, all modules in app will be able to access the services of moduleA and moduleB. That's why you don't need to inject moduleB in moduleA. This is how dependencies work in angular.

If you prefer moduleA to only be injected in moduleB (because it's not needed in mainController), you can simply remove moduleA and ServiceA from app module and inject them only in moduleB.

```
var app = angular.module('moduleB', ['moduleA']);
```

See here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/334d0ubn/)