# How to test the config function of an Angular module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I'm defining some setup code in the `config` function of an Angular `module` that I want to unit test. It is unclear to me how I should do this. Below is a simplified testcase that shows how I'm getting stuck:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myModule', []).config(['$http', '$log', function($http, $log) {
    $http.get('/api/getkey').then(function success(response) {
        $log.log(response.data);
    });
}]);

describe('myModule', function() {
    it('logs a key obtained from XHR', inject(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/getkey').respond(200, '12345');
        angular.module('myModule');
        $httpBackend.flush();
    }));
});
```

This is clearly not the right way because I get the following error:

```
Error: No pending request to flush !
```

A complete, ready-to-run Angular project with the above testing code can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/UUDigitalHumanitieslab/angular-karma-module-config-testcase). If you know what to do with this scenario, please answer here on Stack Overflow. Bonus points if you also submit a pull request to the GitHub repo.

Comment: As @mzulch's answer points out, you can only inject providers (not instances) into config blocks. So how would you expect a unit test to succeed if your code isn't functional?

Comment: A question can be misguided (like this question, as I now understand). This can be pointed out in an answer. A great answer explains three things: (1) how to use services globally in a module, (2) how to test `config` blocks, (3) why you can't have both at the same time.

Comment: I guess I was more curious about your process. I usually write tests after I'm confident that my code works, but now that I think about it, some people insist on writing tests first and writing their code to fit the test. Fair enough.

Comment: There is a third way in between: write the code first, then write the test to check whether the code works. I think that's what I was doing here. Thanks for drawing my attention to this, I had not reflected so precisely on my order of programming and testing before. :-)

Comment: The fact that you're testing unworkable code doesn't add clarity to the question. Regarding config vs run and serviceName vs serviceNameProvider, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33704523/37315010). There are two different injectors for config and run phases which inject service providers and service instances respectively. Service providers can be made to be available in instance injector but not vice versa. That's why `$http` in `config` block is a conundrum.

Comment: You are right about it complicating the question. For this reason I basically wrote a new version of the question that doesn't have this problem, in my own answer. I would edit the question in place if mzulch had not already answered it so thoroughly. As it stands, I prefer to leave things as they are and award the bounty to mzulch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mzulch is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38961838/1166087) to point out that services cannot be injected in an `angular.module(...).config` block. He also provides the right solution for the scenario where you actually need to use services in module initialization code: use the `.run` block instead of the `.config` block. His answer works perfectly for this scenario.

The question of how to write a unit test for the `.config` block remains. Let's adapt the naieve code from my question to a scenario where `.config` is actually warranted. The following snippet injects a provider dependency instead of a service dependency:

```js
angular.module('myModule', []).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true);
}]);

describe('myModule', function() {
    it('configures the $http service to combine response processing via $applyAsync', inject(function($httpProvider) {
        angular.module('myModule');
        expect($httpProvider.useApplyAsync()).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

This time, the implementation of `'myModule'` is correct. The unit test however, which is analogous to the attempt in my question, is still incorrect. Now Karma gives me the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $httpProviderProvider <- $httpProvider
```

This cryptical error is coming from the `inject` which is passed as the second argument to the `it`. Note how `Provider` is being stuttered. This is caused by the fact that `inject` is looking for *the provider for `$httpProvider`*. A "meta provider", as we may call it. Such things don't exist in the Angular framework, but `inject` is trying it anyway because *it expects you to only ask for service dependencies*. Services do have providers, for example, `$http` has `$httpProvider`.

So `inject` (full name: `angular.mock.inject`, here available globally) is not the right way to get hold of `$httpProvider` in the testcase. The right way is to define an anonymous module configuration function using `module` (`angular.mock.module`) which closes over a variable in which we can capture the provider. This works because providers *can* be injected at configuration time (see the [link](https://medium.com/@a_eife/testing-config-and-run-blocks-in-angularjs-1809bd52977e) at the bottom of [mzulch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38961838/1166087) as well as my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39007140/1166087) to my other question for details on configuration time vs run time). It looks like this:

```js
var $httpProvider;

beforeEach(function() {
    module(function(_$httpProvider_) {
        // this is a .config function
        $httpProvider = _$httpProvider_;
    });
    // after this I can use inject() to make the magic happen
});
```

Another mistake in my naieve testcase is that I'm trying to execute `'myModule'`s configuration steps by calling `angular.module('myModule')`. For testcase purposes, I should be using the global `module` (`angular.mock.module`) instead, and the wisest place to do so is in the `beforeEach` fixture. In conclusion, the following code does the job:

```js
describe('myModule', function() {
    var $httpProvider;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module(function(_$httpProvider_) {
            $httpProvider = _$httpProvider_;
        });
        module('myModule');
    });

    it('configures the $http service to combine response processing via $applyAsync', function() {
        inject();  // enforces all the module config steps
        expect($httpProvider.useApplyAsync()).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I opted to put the `inject()` at the start of my testcase, but I could also put it at the end of the `beforeEach`. The advantage of the latter approach would be that I can write the call to `inject` in one place and not need to repeat it in every testcase. The advantage of the approach actually taken here is that more modules can be added to the [injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) in later `beforeEach`es or even in individual testcases.

I pushed this alternative solution to a new branch on [GitHub](https://github.com/UUDigitalHumanitieslab/angular-karma-module-config-testcase/tree/fix-jgonggrijp).

Answer (score 5):

Use `run` instead of `config` if your initialization requires services to be injected. The `config` function can only receive providers and constants as parameters, not instantiated services like `$http` ([relevant docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)).

```
angular.module('myModule', []).run(['$http', '$log', function($http, $log) {
    ...
}]);
```

Initialize your module for testing

```
beforeEach(module('myModule'));

it('logs a key obtained from XHR', inject(function($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/getkey').respond(200, '12345');
    $httpBackend.flush();
}));
```

So the full working version looks like

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myModule', []).run(['$http', '$log', function($http, $log) {
    $http.get('/api/getkey').then(function success(response) {
        $log.log(response.data);
    });
}]);

describe('myModule', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    it('logs a key obtained from XHR', inject(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/getkey').respond(200, '12345');
        $httpBackend.flush();
    }));
});
```

Also, here's an example of testing the config block to check that a method on a provider was called: https://medium.com/@a_eife/testing-config-and-run-blocks-in-angularjs-1809bd52977e#71e0

Comment: I like your answer, but you can further increase its value if you take the insights from that last external link and include them in your answer. After all, the question is *how to test the config function*. You may alter the example for this purpose, e.g. by replacing `$http` and `$log` by providers that can be used in a `config` block. In addition, it would be nice if you could further explain why `$http` cannot be injected in the `config`; after all, the docs also state that services are a special case of providers.

Comment: I pushed your solution to [GitHub](https://github.com/UUDigitalHumanitieslab/angular-karma-module-config-testcase/tree/fix-mzulch).

Comment: Congratulations with the bounty, I think you deserved it. I will probably accept my own answer, as it more literally addresses the title of the question, but I'm postponing the decision for a bit in case somebody provides arguments I didn't think of.