# module.value not updating across app and $provide injection breaks app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

This problem is very confusing even for me, and so I am going to try and simplify it step by step as best as I can.

**1**

I start off with the app by simply calling `angular.module('app', [])`. Then in that same set up I add a value:

```
angular.module('app', []).value('Storage', {})
```

I set the value to `{}` because there is nothing to store yet.

**2**

I have a series of "init" controllers to ensure that everything boots correctly. Inside the catalog controller I want to update the `Storage` value.

I'm in strict mode so my set up is as followed:

```
angular.module('app').controller('Init', InitController);

InitController.$inject = ['Storage', '$q', '$http'];

function InitController(Storage, $q, $http){
   var getDeferred = $q.defer();
   var got = getDeferred.promise;

   $http({
       // some code to do stuff
   }).then(function(data){
       getDeferred.resolve(data);   
   });
   got.then(function(data){

       // then I should I be able to update and set the new value here
       Storage = data; // thats what everything online showed me
   });
}
```

**3**

I have my Main Controller and I do my normal injections and whatnot:

```
angular.module('app').controller('Main', MainController);
MainController.$inject = ['Storage'];
function mainController(Storage){
    console.log(Storage) // shows an empty object still
}
```

This didn't make sense so I went back to the step two and figured well what if I use the `$provide` service and get the value that way, that should work yes?

```
// Step 2 revised
angular.module('app').controller('Init', InitController);

InitController.$inject = ['$provide', '$q', '$http'];

function InitController($provide $q, $http){
   var getDeferred = $q.defer();
   var got = getDeferred.promise;

   $http({
       // some code to do stuff
   }).then(function(data){
       getDeferred.resolve(data);   
   });
   got.then(function(data){

       // tried to set it up a new way
       $provide.value('Storage', data);
   });
}
```

This just straight up crashed everything and I get this error

`Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=[object Object]rovideProvider%%3C-%%24provide%%3C-%CatalogInit`

which is barely making sense to be because all my dependencies are there and spelled correctly. So I'm at a loss. Google has been no help either, because everything just repeats it self.

Answer (score 0):

The code has a typo:

```
function InitController($provide $q, $http){
```

But the main problem is that `$provide` cannot be used in run phase.

Although [it is possible to use the services from config phase in run phase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704523/3731501), this will lead to unforseen circumstances. If there's no good reason, this should be considered a hack and be avoided.

It depends on how `Storage` is used. It may be a route resolver. Or the reference to the object should be kept:

```
   got.then(function(data){
       angular.extend(Storage, data);
   });
```

If `Storage` object is changed multiple times, it should be emptied first.