# AngularJS module.controller vs $controllerProvider.register

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to add controller dynamically in my AngularJS application.
On sub-domain, I have `anotherController.js` file.
Here's `anotherController.js` content:

```
function anotherControllerWrapper() {
    return ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {

        $scope.doWork = function () {
        //...doing some work...
            alert('work done');
        };

        $scope.doWork();
    }];
};
```

Also I have wrote `runtimeController` provider to be able to use `$controllerProvider` in runtime:

```
app.provider('runtimeController', function () {
    var controllerProvider = null;

    this.setControllerProvider = function (cp) {
        controllerProvider = cp;
    };

    this.$get = function () {
        return {
            registerController: function (controllerName, controllerConstructor) {
                if (!controllerProvider.has(controllerName)) {
                    controllerProvider.register(controllerName, controllerConstructor);
                }
            }
        };
    };
});
```

Here's `config` section of application:

```
app.config(function($controllerProvider, runtimeControllerProvider) {
    runtimeControllerProvider.setControllerProvider($controllerProvider);
});
```

I'm receiving controller's code over http (inside another controller), so it looks like this:

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$state', '$http', 'runtimeController',
   function ($scope, $state, $http, runtimeController) {

    $http.get('http://someUrl/anotherController.js')
        .then(
            function(sucess){
                var evaluated = new Function('return ' + success.data)();
                var ctrl = evaluated();
                // routing to ui state with specified 'anotherController' works
                // no 'anotherController' in app._invokeQueue 
                runtimeController.registerController('anotherController', ctrl);
                // routing to ui state with specified 'anotherController' constanly fails
                // 'anotherController' appears in app._invokeQueue
                //app.controller('anotherController', ctrl);  

                //--registering new UI route with 'anotherController' as controller here

                $state.go('anotherState');

            },
            function(error){ alert('something went wrong!'); },
        );

}]);
```

Ui states are also added dymanically, **after** I'm adding controller.
Can someone explain me please, what's happening and what's difference between `$controllerProvider.register` and `module.controller`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module methods (`controller`, `directive`, etc) result in adding a config block (`_configBlocks`) that is executed on application initialization. Once the application has passed config phase, it won't execute newly added config blocks, so `app.controller(...)` has no effect during run phase.

As [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704523/3731501) shows, `runtimeController` implementation can be simplified to

```
app.config(($provide, $controllerProvider) => {
  $provide.value('$controllerProvider', $controllerProvider);
});
```

`eval` should be avoided for numerous reasons. Considering that the script is loaded from a domain that is allowed by CORS and doesn't require to be `eval`ed, a suitable alternative is to load it as a script. This will require to patch AngularJS API to allow late component registrations, similarly to how ocLazyLoad does - or just use ocLazyLoad, because it already does that.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, that's what I was looking for. Regarding `eval` - I used it, because I cant predict what exact script I will need - I receive list of files to download from CDN after login. Thanks for the advice about ocLazyLoad - will take a look!

Comment: You're welcome. There's no need for eval, unless you have to do replacements in script body (e.g. `.controller` to `.config` - which can be handled by patching API), You can load a script with $.getScript, or System.import, or basically by appending <script> dynamically. Yes, ocLazyLoad is there for a long time and is battle-proven, so there's no need to reinvent it.