# AngularJS 1.6 - On a config phase $http defaults requestError, broadcast event to main scope?

Tags: angularjs

I need to broadcast an event after receiving a $http.defaults request error (400 status code, mainly) but I cannot access $rootScope within config phase.

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.config(['$httpProvider','$injector', function($httpProvider, $injector) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function($q) {
        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                /*
                Doesn't work: 
                $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
                $rootScope.$emit("RESPONSE_ERROR");
                */
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);
}]);
app.controller("Controller",function($scope){
    $scope.$on("RESPONSE_ERROR",function(event,params){
        alert("WORKING!");
    });
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code injecting `$rootScope` into custom interceptor function.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.config(['$httpProvider','$injector', function($httpProvider, $injector) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$rootScope', '$q', function($rootScope, $q) {
        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('RESPONSE_ERROR', {
                    // Custom properties
                });
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);
}]);
```

Comment: I feel so stupid I forgot to inject $rootScope within the interceptors... Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the fact that there are two different injectors, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704523/3731501). In the code above `$injector` is the one that was injected during config phase, it deals with service providers.

Another one should be injected during run phase in order to get access to service instances like `$rootScope`:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector) { ... });
```

As another answer already explains, `$rootScope` can be injected into the interceptor directly. While `$injector` is a common way to avoid circular dependencies in interceptors and inject `$http` there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, @Izagkaretos answer worked in my case, so I'll accept his answer.

Comment: No problem. Even though it doesn't explain why this happens, it's correct.